# Learning Python : import exists

Tags: if-statement

I am learning Python and I am a super beginner!
I just completed an exercise and wanted to create variations of it.
My question is, when using the **IF/ELSE** statement  how can I avoid using
*"out_file = open(to_file,'w') out_file.write(indata)"* twice. 
Thanks in advance!

```
from sys import argv
from os.path import exists

script, from_file, to_file = argv

print "Copying from %s to %s" % (from_file, to_file)

in_file = open(from_file)
indata = in_file.read()

print "The input file is %d bytes long" % len(indata)

if exists(to_file):
    print "File already exists, override?"
    raw_input()
else:
    out_file = open(to_file,'w')
    out_file.write(indata)

out_file = open(to_file,'w')
out_file.write(indata)

print"Done."

out_file.close()
in_file.close()
```

Comment: I think you've stumbled upon one of the main reasons why [functions](http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/functions.html#function-parameters) exist :)

Comment: As I said, I just started to dive into the world of coding. So please, give me an example so I can learn! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Currently your script doesn't genuinely consider the user's input for whether to overwrite, and you overwrite regardless of their input. It looks like you want to consider their input, so I would recommend something like:

```
proceed = False
if exists(to_file):
    print "File already exists, override?"
    ans = raw_input("y/n: ")
    if ans == "y":
        proceed = True
else:
    proceed = True

if proceed:
    out_file = open(to_file,'w')
    out_file.write(indata)
```

Also, you'll probably want to do some error handling if the `from_file` doesn't exist, as in that circumstance the call to `open()` will raise an `IOError` -- see https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open

Comment: I like the use of `proceed`  turn 2 nested conditions into one flag for writing the file.  I also like that this answer opens the output file only _if_ the user is going to write to it.  And calling out the need to handle more errors - very nice.

Comment: Thank you very much. I want to consider user input only if file already exists.